# jqgrid + add form + datepicker

Tags: jqgrid, datepicker

There was a problem.
In the form of adding my two fields with the date. I connect to them datepicker

```
beforeShowForm: pickLedgerDates,

function pickLedgerDates(){
    $("#payment_date,#invoice_date").datepicker();
}
```

in the form itself when you click on the first field, there is a calendar, pick a date, all is well.
when you click on the second field, polyavlyaetsya calendar, pick a date and the date placed in the first field and the focus there is on it. and the window does not close the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

why can't you put datepicker when you are defining colModal

see for example

`{ name: 'date',height:100, index: 'date', align: 'right',sortable:false, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd/m/y' }, editable: true,editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{readonly: 'readonly', dataInit:function(el) { $(el).datepicker();}}},`

give this with your both date fields and then it should work.

Comment: I formed colModel via php array + json_decode
have this
"editoptions":{"dataInit":"function(el){ setTimeout(\"$(el).datepicker();\",3000); }"}